# Swift use prepareForSegue in indexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

i have a model class and two tableView Controller. This class in Integer value. This class in value send to other class with prepareforsegue method. But i can not prepareforsegue get tableView indexpath. i' m doing wrong?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let subCategory: SubCategoryVC = segue.destinationViewController as SubCategoryVC

    let indexPath = self.categoryTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    model = arrList[indexPath?.row] **//incorrect line**

    subCategory.getCatID = model.categoryID
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. i found it. This problem is optional. :(

```
let indexPath = self.categoryTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()**!**
```

I put the exclamation point on the end of the line and correct.

safe method;

```
if let indexPath = categoryTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    // do the work here
}
```

Comment: But this will crash if the expression returns nil

Answer (score 11):

`indexPath?.row` returns optional value. You can't use it in array subacript. You have to uwrap it first. Here is example:

```
if let indexPath = categoryTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    // do the work here
}
```

Comment: This is not a function anymore; use: categoryTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow